# Справка Stack Overflow в видео формате

Tags: обсуждение, справка

Как мне кажется, сегодня не все новые участники готовы потратить серьезное 
количество времени на изучение всех правил сообщества. Вместо этого, люди поступают по наитию, и лишь в случае неудачного действия, обращаются к предложенным в комментариях статьям из справочного центра. Улучшить эту ситуацию, на мой взгляд, может справка в видео формате, так как просмотр видео проще сам по себе, а информация – нагляднее.

Спешу поделиться первой версией видео справки, в которой рассказываются основные механики сайта.

[image]

Если вы знаете, как можно улучшить видео, а также у вас есть любой другой отзыв, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его в ответе к этому вопросу. Мы обязательно учтем любые замечания! Более того, при желании, вы можете предложить вашу версию видео справки для [какого–либо раздела](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) [справочного центра](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Если вам понравилось данное видео, пожалуйста, поделитесь им со своими коллегами в соц. сетях или личном общении. Чем больше людей понимают механики сайта, тем больше хороших вопросов будет в базе знаний!

Comment: Мне кажется, заманить людей смотреть видео-справку еще сложнее чем читать текстовую...

Comment: Если предложить человеку прочитать скрипт этого видео или просмотреть само видео, предполагаю, выбор будет в сторону видео. Более того, за счет наглядности, с большой вероятностью, человек вынесет из видео больше, чем из текста.

Comment: Надо добавить ссылку на видео из меню справки вверху страницы.

Comment: @alexolut Обязательно добавим ссылку в несколько основных разделов справки.

Comment: чем больше форматов тем лучше. В качестве справки, *текст* нормальный. Чисто личное ощущение ни к чему не относящееся: голос на технаря не тянет (ощущение рекламы в shopping mall)--я бы участников лучше послушал-- и эффекты чересчур назойливо повторяются без смысловой нагрузки (бывает, если человек первый раз до видео-редактора добрался). Если назначение видео, чтобы вместо чтения справки использовать, то обзор функциональности достаточен. Хотя научится по нему новому человеку нереально наверно (можно потестировать), да и не должно быть такой цели: сайт рассчитан на постепенное усвоение...

Comment: ...[продолжение](очки репутации не столько о привилегиях, сколько о том что человек достаточно освоился, чтобы больше функционала на сайте использовать)¶ Видео с другой целью (why & getting started) с акцентом на мотивацию (миссию): зачем и как задавать вопросы, зачем отвечать на вопросы, для первого знакомства, в чём отличие от других технических форумов (вербовка другими словами) можно было бы в tour поместить. [примеры видео, особенно о "challenge, mastery, making a contribution" (за пределами моих навыков)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54659/137096)

Comment: @PavelMayorov с учетом количества просмотров всевозможных видео-недо-курсов по программированию, как раз видео скорее посмотрят, чем справку прочитают, хотя это конечно тоже не показатель

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky есть предложение [добавить видео при создании вопроса (2 место конечно получше)](http://image.prntscr.com/image/b554c0dbb6a7487db6bdc543613385f0.png), на 1 место или на 2. Так будет больше шансов, что новые пользователи посмотрят видео и у них будет больше понимания о работе сайта. Даже наверное будет лучше поднять его над блоком "как задавать вопросы".

Comment: @Alex Спасибо, отличное предложение! Все блоки боковой панели можно настроить через Transifex. С большой вероятность, мы сможем это сделать, если видео окажется полезным. Первым шагом, на мой взгляд, будет добавить видео в справку.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky видео в любо случае будет полезно, т.к. читать справки на сайтах без мотивации никто не любит.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky учитывая принцип дизайна: "you are not your user" (то что для нас видео понятно, не очевидно что это поможет новому участнику), есть ли возможность такие вещи A/B потестировать? (часть людей получают ссылку на видео, часть на текст справки—через какое-то время сравнить как это на вопросы повлияло: сравнить голоса, долю закрытых, время первого ответа, принят/не принят  ответ через неделю итд).

Comment: @jfs Идея крайне интересная, не понятно как реализовать. Прочтение (или просмотр) справки – дело сугубо личное. Мы не можем кого–либо заставить. Единственный раз, когда участник получает строгую рекомендацию к прочтению документов – в письме, которое, в основном, сопровождается блокировкой учетной записи в следствии большого количества плохих вопросов. Было бы здорово найти способ провести тест.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как реализовать: в то место куда вы при создании вопроса хотите ссылку на видео/само видео поместить, вы *в качестве альтернативы* для *некоторой части* пользователей возвращаете ссылку на текстовую справку/выдержку из справки. Никого ничего не надо заставлять (люди могут и многие будут игнорировать как видео так и текст). Позже сравниваете результаты. Можно третий вариант проверить: не приводить ни видео ни тестовую справку.

Answer (score 6):

Не подумайте чего неправильного, просто ответ не поместится в комментарий.

Видео - [мейнстрим](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC). Не особо осведомлен в реальных цифрах, но если посмотреть на общий тренд, то справка и введение в цифровые продукты не лишены внимания этой формой передачи информации. Обратите внимание на [Google Developers](https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers/) или реанимированный [Google Help](https://www.youtube.com/user/Googlehelp), на [Free Code Camp](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ).

В любом случае, видео реально удобно для правильного направления течения мысли собеседника. Например, вот [ссылка](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=5m34s)

Ссылки на разделы

- [8s Что такое Stack Overflow?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=8s)
- [20s Публикация вопроса](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=20s)
- [1m3s Голосование](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=1m3s)
- [1m51s Репутация и привилегии](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=1m51s)
- [2m55s Метки](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=2m55s)
- [4m11s Знаки](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=4m11s)
- [5m10s Лицензия](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=5m10s)
- [5m34s Девиз](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=5m34s)

Еще ...

### YouTube

[Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky), можно добавить в подпись к видео, YouTube сам превратит строки в ссылки

```
8s Что такое Stack Overflow?
20s Публикация вопроса
1m3s Голосование
1m51s Репутация и привилегии
2m55s Метки
4m11s Знаки
5m10s Лицензия
5m34s Девиз
```

### HTML

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=8s">Что такое Stack Overflow?</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=20s">Публикация вопроса</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=1m3s">Голосование</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=1m51s">Репутация и привилегии</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=2m55s">Метки</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=4m11s">Знаки</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=5m10s">Лицензия</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=5m34s">Девиз</a>
```

### MD

```
[8s Что такое Stack Overflow?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=8s)
[20s Публикация вопроса](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=20s)
[1m3s Голосование](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=1m3s)
[1m51s Репутация и привилегии](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=1m51s)
[2m55s Метки](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=2m55s)
[4m11s Знаки](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=4m11s)
[5m10s Лицензия](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=5m10s)
[5m34s Девиз](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY&t=5m34s)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил ссылки.