# Обратная связь и инициативы на интернациональных сайтах

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Коллеги,

На MSE появился пост Николаса [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/348096), в котором он предложил высказывать в ответах предложения по данному вопросу.

Поскольку не все на русскоязычном сайте знают о происходящем на MSE - мы решили оповестить бОльший круг участников, опубликовав эту тему и у нас.

Если у вас есть предложения и вам позволяет английский - вэлком на MSE, пишите. Если есть предложения, но не позволяет английский - пишите в эту тему ваши мысли - поможем перевести.

Перевод ниже - если видите, что можно поправить - правьте.

---

Конечная цель Stack Overflow — создать, с помощью нашего сообщества, библиотеку детальных ответов на каждый существующий вопрос по программированию. Вместе с нашими бравыми участниками мы отправились в изумительное путешествие после запуска Stack Overflow на разных языках за последние несколько лет.

[image]

И мы идём дальше! Если посмотреть на подсайты сети как на один объединённый  интернациональный сайт, то он будет вторым наиболее активным сообществом после Stack Overflow на английском языке (по количеству вопросов в день). Глядя на наши интернациональные сайты и на остальную часть сети Stack Exchange, я ясно вижу, что мы упустили очень важную вещь: мы забываем, что каждый сайт сети чем-то отличается от такого же интернационального сайта. Я имею ввиду, что у каждого интернационального сайта свой собственный “*Двунаправленный канал коммуникации между компанией и сообществом*”.

#### Как сейчас происходит коммуникация между компанией и сообществом?

За период с 01.01.2018 по 15.06.2018 было опубликовано сотрудниками компании:

- на сайте Meta Stack Exchange: 282 ответа.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на русском: 48 ответа.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на испанском: 28 ответов.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на португальском: 10 ответов.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на японском: 1 ответ.
- на сайте Meta Stack Overflow на английском: 412 ответов.

Мне кажется, что если кто-то из компании не говорит на языке сообщества, то он будет в изоляции от остальной части сети. А мы не хотим чтобы такое случалось. Наша философия успеха полагается в первую очередь на наше сообщество. Мы постепенно делаем наши сайты лучшим местом в сети Интернет где можно задавать вопросы и опираемся в этой работе на обратную связь от вас. Без возможности диалога с сообществом, без того чтобы слушать вас — мы вряд ли бы что-то сделали.

#### Как был устроен процесс?

Раньше у каждого интернационального сайта был один выделенный менеджер сообщества, который знал язык сообщества и английский. То, как такие менеджеры сообщества работали с сообществам различалось у каждого сайта сети. Каждый интернациональный сайт имел отдельные инициативы и разные по приоритету задачи, которые почти не пересекались между сообществами. Это означает что КМы часто делали одну и ту же работу по решению похожих проблем на разных интернациональных сайтах. И можно было сохранить б*о*льшую часть усилий, работая вместе.

#### Улучшение коммуникаций

Что если мы пойдём другим путём? Что если мы будем способны обмениваться инициативами между интернациональными сайтами, переиспользовать опыт других сообществ и действовать на базе обратной связи от всех сайтов? Первый шаг по направлению к этой цели - это наладить коммуникационный канал для существующих идей, инициатив и обратной связи между компанией и сообществами так же как и между сообществами.

Самый большой вызов в этой ситуации в том, что все сообщества, включая компанию, разговаривают на разных языках. Это не чья-то ошибка — просто такова реальность. Поэтому я хочу поделиться с вами некоторыми мыслями о том, как мог бы работать подобный коммуникационный канал.

## Обратная связь и инициативы на интернациональных сайтах

> **TL;DR**
>
> - Нам нужен канал взаимодействия между компанией и интернациональными сайтами, а также каналы между сообществами. На текущий момент наилучшее место это [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).
> - В дискуссиях на MSE стоит вести обсуждения на английском, а интернациональные сайты будут продолжать вести дискуссию на своём языке.
> - Инициативы компании будут публиковаться на английском языке на MSE и нам нужна помощь волонтёров-переводчиков, чтобы публиковать переводы на локальных мета-сайтах.
> - Инициативы сообщества будем публиковать на соответствующих мета-сайтах и их надо переводить для публикации на MSE. И тогда они могут получать распространение среди других сайтов сети на их метах.
> - Мы будем поддерживать дискуссии в синхронизированном состоянии на всех мета-сайтах сети.
> - Когда дискуссия на интернациональном сайте почти завершена, нам снова понадобится помощь волонтёров для того чтобы сделать сводку о том, что было сказано сообществом и запостить ответом на MSE.

[image]

За последние несколько лет мы на SOru опробовали несколько интересных инициатив ([например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6)), мы начали несколько социальных инициатив ([например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4191/6)), мы интегрировали / активировали несколько интересных фич движка ([например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6)). Меня беспокоит, что большинство этих инициатив даже не были предложены другим интернациональным сайтам. Я думаю, что ситуация на других сайтах сходная: каждый сайт имеет свой набор инициатив, о которых никто не знает за пределами этого сайта.

Это может привести к ситуации, когда очень важные фичи для интернациональных сайтов не будут реализованы в базовом движке только потому, что они кажутся нужными слишком малому числу пользователей (если мы посмотрим на них в контексте одного конкретного сайта сети). Интернациональные сайты не такие большие по отдельности, но, как уже было сказано, все вместе мы занимаем второе место в сети. Если всем сообществам нужна какая-то фича в движке, то я надеюсь, что она получит соответствующий приоритет. Однако первый шаг — это начать обсуждать инициативы совместно.

#### Как распространять инициативы между интернациональными сайтами?

Когда мы думаем о том, как выстроить коммуникации между сайтами, мы должны иметь ввиду следующее:

- Процесс должен быть масштабируемым. Представьте себе, что у нас есть сотня интернациональных сайтов. Процесс должен работать для любого числа сайтов без затруднений.
- Автор инициативы не может говорить на всех языках, на которых говорят интернациональные сайты.
- Мы хотим чтобы как можно больше людей просмотрело как можно больше инициатив, включая пользователей с различных англоязычных сайтов и сотрудников компании.
- Должен быть предусмотрен способ интернациональным сообществам обсудить инициативу на своём собственном языке.
- Итоги дискуссии на интернациональных сайтах нужно распространить на остальную сеть - и в частности на все остальные интернациональные сайты.

Учитывая всё это, хочу рассказать как мог бы выглядеть процесс:

1. Автор инициативы (КМ или участник) должен запостить вопрос на MSE, пометив его специальной меткой (скажем, [international](/questions/tagged/international)). Язык вопроса - английский.
2. Участники, которые знают хотя бы два языка могут выступить волонтёрами: перевести вопрос и запостить его на интернациональную мету.
3. Когда перевод опубликован на интернациональном сайте, переводчик добавляет ссылку на исходный вопрос на MSE. И, пожалуйста, добавьте ссылку в перевод на  MSE. Это поможет поддерживать дискуссию между метами в синхронизированном состоянии.
4. После того, как сообщество обсудит инициативу, нам нужен доброволец, кто опубликует сводку обсуждения на интернациональной мете в виде ответа в топик на MSE. Сводка должна быть на английском. Я думаю, что возможно будет неплохо держать один вики-ответ со сводкой ответов с интернациональных сайтов. В этом случае мы сможем держать такую сводку наверху, закрепив её галкой.
5. Если у кого-либо будут мысли по поводу инициативы, он может постить их на любую мету, в том числе и MSE.

В случае инициативы сообщества, процесс будет почти такой же, только с одним отличием: инициатива начинается на мете интернационального сайта и её нужно перевести на английский и запостить на MSE. А после этого все шаги идентичны.

Подобный процесс позволит компании понимать все потребности интернациональных сайтов. Также, процесс должен помочь интернациональным сообществам обмениваться идеями по конкретным вопросам, обмениваться инициативами и видеть какие восхитительные вещи происходят у соседей по сети.

### Пожалуйста, расскажите что вы думаете

Мы хотим сделать наши интернациональные сайты лучшим местом в сети интернет для вопросов по программированию на родном языке участника. Первый шаг - создать платформу взаимодействия сообществ друг с другом и с компанией.
Если у вас есть идеи о том, как мы можем улучшить процесс в направлении к этой цели - пожалуйста, сообщите нам!

### Ссылки на эту инициативу на интернациональных метах

- на SOpt: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7308/112052
- на SOes: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3658/324
- на SOja: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2748
- на SOru: [Обратная связь и инициативы на интернациональных сайтах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7847/15479)
- на RusSE: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/339/182097

**Обновление по поводу наименования метки**

- [Локализация программного обеспечения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) - стандартный термин с вполне понятным значением, который, как мне кажется, не очень подходит для этой инициативы.
- Интернациональный  Stack Overflow - термин с довольно узким смыслом. Инициатива касается именно интернациональных сайтов. На мой взгляд, это сайты, где весь **UI не на английском**. На сегодняшний день у нас есть  интернациональные Stack Overflows сайты и [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).
- Мне кажется, что чем короче метка, тем лучше. Думаю, лучшим выбором будет "international" (или "international*s*"). По той же причине мы не используем "stack-overflow-site".

У нас всё ещё много вопросов по поводу метки. Если у вас есть идеи по поводу улучшения наименования, пожалуйста, поделитесь своими мыслями!

Answer (score 5):

Продублирую свой ответ сюда: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315320/260198

Как по мне, одна из ключевых проблем - нас (локальные сайты) не воспринимают всерьёз. Очень часто когда тот же Шог отвечает, в ответах мелькает **major language**. Понятно дело, что они ориентируются на большинство, но порой складывается ощущение, что они просто игнорят локальные запрос или откладывают в дальний ящик. К примеру, из последнего, глобальный вопрос про переводы: [How localized sites could translate strings before update actually rolled out?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314599/260198). Даже никто не ответил. У @alexolut тоже много подобных вопросов.

Касательно инициативы. До нас инициативы с MSE не доходят или доходят с опозданием (как было с обсуждением CoC). Я думал, что подобным должен КМ заниматься. Но сейчас КМ нет, не ясно, кто взвалит на себя это работу теперь.

Про проблему с синхронизацией, думаю, особо не стоит расписывать. Синхронизировать ответы между всеми сайтами - адский труд. Как это разруливать, тоже не ясно.

Я предложил спец. метку ввести для таких инициатив/обсуждений. Вопросы с такой меткой автоматом будут публиковаться на локальных сайтах на английском языке. А дальше сообщество будет уже думать/переводить. Так, по крайней мере, решим вопрос информирования на ранних этапах.

Comment: Что-то разные ответы получились

Comment: @alexolut разве? :D Часть про владение языком я упустил осознанно.

Comment: @Suvitruf Да они и популярные английские запросы тоже вполне успешно игнорят, взять хотя бы [сайдбар](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/346987), удаление специфики сайтов, [значок "новичка"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/346987) и т.д. Поэтому не уверен, что дело в языке. Просто они к мнению широких масс вообще не сильно внимательны (скажем политкорректно).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov там хоть обсуждение есть. А то, что просят мнения, но не прислушиваются, эт да)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Все упомянутые вами решения спущены сверху в ультимативной форме, изначально без права обжалования, потому что их функция — генерировать/экономить деньги. Реализовывать в первую очередь тоже будут то, что генерирует/экономит деньги. У ассоциаций вопросов хорошие шансы, например — просто надо подождать, пока "гениальные идеи" изнутри компании иссякнут.

Comment: @Athari иссякнут ли...